# Using Haxe on Windows after installing with the automatic installer

Tags: terminal, haxe

I recently installed Haxe on Windows 7 (64 bit) using the default installer. After installing it, I tried creating these files in a folder called Haxe Examples:

`compile.hxml`:

```
-js test.js
-main Test
```

`Test.hx`:

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        trace("Hello World !");
    }
}
```

When I run compile.hxml by double-clicking on the `compile.hxml` file, I get the following message in the terminal:

> Error: Invalid class name for class Test{

What might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that I accidentally put the source code of `compile.hxml` in `Test.hx`, and vice versa. I switched the names around, and the compiler is working now!

Answer (score 0):

It works here on my machine.

Can you open the command-prompt or terminal, and run `haxe compile.hxml` in that directory?

Perhaps something went weird with the file association for double-clicking the HXML file.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem after installing Haxe on Ubuntu as well.